# Allowed to rename AppComponent?

Tags: angular

Are you allowed to rename the AppComponent to something else?

**From the default, AppComponent:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
}
```

**To a new name, StockholmComponent:**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'stockholm',
    templateUrl: './stockholm.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./stockholm.component.css']
})
export class StockholmComponent {
    title = 'Stockholm';
}
```

Comment: a small trail would have helped

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631019/4654957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely. Any valid TypeScript class name can be used that doesn't conflict with other imports.

`AppComponent` is only used in examples to make it clear that it is the root component without also adding `@NgModule({ bootstrap: AppComponent, ...})`